# Spring+Hibernate+JPA: Add dynamic tables/entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, dynamic

An application permits admin users to upload CSV-files and save them as database tables.

The application uses Spring+JPA+Hibernate to access the database. How can I access the dynamically added new tables/entities to the system, without restarting or even recoding the system?

Comment: What prevents you from storing CSV files in a single table? Are there differences between those files in terms of data types, number of columns, etc. ?

Comment: Yes, they all have different column formats.